# creating half star rating in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, rating

I'm using C#,VS2010 to develop my ASP.NET web app, I want to create a rating system in which user can select his rate by stars, something like AjaxControlToolkit rating, I've used this control, but is there any way that user can select half stars? for instance I have 5 stars and user can select 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2 and ... up to 5?

what about telerik or other custom controls? I'm looking for the ability to select and display half stars, is it possible? I've seen several sites that display half stars in addition to stars

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this jquery plugin, [raty](http://www.wbotelhos.com/raty/). It allows you to have half star ratings.

You can use ajax to post and a asp.net webservice as the backend.

I do not know of a asp.net custom control. But writing your own isn't very difficult.
In this case, you don't really need a custom control.